# PyMuPDF - read/write text box

Tags: python, pdf

I've been able to read the content of PDFs with: PYMuPDF using code similar to the following:

```
myfile = r"C:\users\xxx\desktop\testpdf1.pdf"
doc  =fitz.open(myfile)
page=doc[1]
text = page.getText("text")
```

to read the contents of PDF files, however I can't read text box annotations is there a way to do this?

Comment: To clarify, by text box annotations I mean the comments created with Comments->Drawing Markups-> Text Box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`firstAnnot`](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/#Page.firstAnnot) on the page object. Once you have an annotation object it looks like you can call [`next`](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot/#Annot.next) on it and get the others. Note the [example](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot/#example) at the bottom of the `Annot` page.

I created a PDF from a Word document and added one text box and one sticky note. The following code printed the contents of each. Look inside [`info`](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot/#Annot.info) for other information you may want.

```
import fitz

pdf = fitz.open('WordTest.pdf')
page = pdf[0]
annot = page.firstAnnot
print(annot.info['content'])
next_annot = annot.next
print(next_annot.info['content'])
pdf.close()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. I tried running this code and don't get any output. However, if  I add in print(annot) it prints the following: 'FreeText' annotation on page 0 of C:\users\xxx\desktop\testpdf2.pdf and if I add `print(annot.widget_text)` I get "    print(annot.widget_text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'widget_text'"

Comment: Unfortunately, without the PDF in question I probably can't be of more help. Is the PDF something you could share or not?

Comment: I'm' not sure how I can upload the file here. However it's just a test file I created, in word, converted to PDF and then added a text box (comments->drawing markups-> add text box) and an annotation (comments->annotation->add sticky note ) . It's actually the conents of the text box that I want to read now, rather than the sticky note (though I'd like to be able to read those too ultimately). Thanks again

Comment: I created my own test PDF and could get the text with the code I've added to my original answer.